# Many to Many relational data not showing in aws amplify dataStore

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify, datastore

data is poperly getting inserted. my problem is when i try fetch it does not provide me [Services] data.

schema.graphql

`

```
type Service @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: public }]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  requestss: [Requests] @manyToMany(relationName: "RequestsService")
}

type Requests @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: public }, { allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID!
  requestType: String
  requestStatus: String
  preferredDateTime: AWSDateTime
  preferences: [String]
  Services: [Service] @manyToMany(relationName: "RequestsService")
}
```

`

model/index.d.ts

``

```
export declare class Requests 
{ readonly id: string; readonly requestType?: string | null; readonly requestStatus?: string | null; readonly preferredDateTime?: string | null; readonly preferences?: (string | null)[] | null; readonly Services?: (RequestsService | null)[] | null; readonly createdAt?: string | null; readonly updatedAt?: string | null; constructor(init: ModelInit<Requests, RequestsMetaData>); static copyOf(source: Requests, mutator: (draft: MutableModel<Requests, RequestsMetaData>) => MutableModel<Requests, RequestsMetaData> | void): Requests; 
}

export declare class Service { readonly id: string; readonly name: string; readonly createdAt?: string | null; readonly updatedAt?: string | null; readonly requestss?: (RequestsService | null)[] | null; constructor(init: ModelInit<Service, ServiceMetaData>); static copyOf(source: Service, mutator: (draft: MutableModel<Service, ServiceMetaData>) => MutableModel<Service, ServiceMetaData> | void): Service; }

export declare class RequestsService { readonly id: string; readonly service: Service; readonly requests: Requests; readonly createdAt?: string | null; readonly updatedAt?: string | null; constructor(init: ModelInit<RequestsService, RequestsServiceMetaData>); static copyOf(source: RequestsService, mutator: (draft: MutableModel<RequestsService, RequestsServiceMetaData>) => MutableModel<RequestsService, RequestsServiceMetaData> | void): RequestsService; }`
```

my insert query

```
import { DataStore } from "aws-amplify";
import { Requests, RequestsService } from "../models";
const newRequests = await DataStore.save(new Requests(request));
const newServices = [];
for (let service of services) {
  const newRequestService = await DataStore.save(
    new RequestsService({ service: service, requests: { id: newRequests.id } })
  );
  newServices.push(newRequestService.id);
}
console.log("newServices", newServices);
await DataStore.save(
  Requests.copyOf(newRequests, (updated) => {
    updated["Services"] = newServices;
  })
);
```

my get query

const existingRequests = await DataStore.query(Requests);

below is my response

```
{
  "_deleted": null,
  "_lastChangedAt": 1648815035648,
  "_version": 2,
  "createdAt": "2022-04-01T12:10:34.293Z",
  "id": "ec446c0f-5acd-4e6c-abd5-13e63faeaeca",
  "owner": "57853bc6-e4cf-4ad1-8ef8-2b0c200cc22f",
  "preferences": ["male"],
  "preferredDateTime": "2022-04-01T12:10:26.332Z",
  "requestStatus": "PENDING",
  "requestType": "PHYSIO",
  "updatedAt": "2022-04-01T12:10:34.293Z"
}
```

It should show in response like

`Services:[ { id,service, requests } ]`

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to get response.

```
const getRequestById = await DataStore.query(Requests, id);
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  let staffServices = [];
  const getServices = await DataStore.query(RequestsService, (c) =>
    c.service("eq", getRequestById.id)
  );
  if (getRequestById.Staff) {
    staffServices = await getStaffServiceById(getRequestById.Staff.id);
  }
  resolve({
    ...getRequestById,
    services: getServices,
    Staff: {
      ...getRequestById.Staff,
      services: staffServices,
    },
  });
})
  .then((promiseResp) => {
    return promiseResp;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    return null;
  });
```

if any other solution is possible. please do ping here